# How to grab the values in a nested object that has functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

i am new to js and destructing or working with objects in js...  i have spent most of the day trying to access this *amount* object variable that in itself is nested within a *balances* object...  i want to get the nested amount (that has the function)

this is the function im using:

```
const newWallet  = async () => {                                                           
   34       const keystore1 = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(keystorelocation, 'utf8'))              
   35       let phrase = await decryptFromKeystore(keystore1, keypasswd)                         
   36       const combowallet= new Wallet(Network.Mainnet, phrase)                               
   37       const bal = await combowallet.getAllBalances()                                       
   38       console.log("bal2:" + bal[2])                                                        
   39       console.log("bal2 address:" + bal[2].address)                                        
   40       console.log("bal2 chain:" + bal[2].chain)                                            
   41       console.log("bal2 balances[0]:" + bal[2].balances[0])                                
   42       console.log(bal[2].balances[1])                                                      
   43       const [ BTC, ETH, thor ] = bal                                                       
   44       console.log("BTC:" + BTC)                                                            
   45       console.log("ETH:" + ETH)                                                            
   46       console.log("THOR:")                                                                 
   47       console.log(thor)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   48       const {chain , address, ...balance } = thor                                                                                  
   49       console.log("balance is:" + balance)                                                                                         
   50       const {balances} = balance                                                                                                   
   51       console.log("balances is:" + balances)                                                                                                                                                                         
   52                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   53                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
   54   }
```

here is the type:

```
type AllBalances = {
    chain: Chain
    address: string
    balances: Balance[] | string
  }
```

i de structured the object via this line

```
const {chain , address, ...balance } = thor
```

got this

```
{ balances: [ { asset: [Object], amount: [Object] } ] }
```

```
{
  asset: { chain: 'THOR', symbol: 'RUNE', ticker: 'RUNE', synth: false },
  amount: {
    type: 'BASE',
    amount: [Function: amount],
    plus: [Function: plus],
    minus: [Function: minus],
    times: [Function: times],
    div: [Function: div],
    lt: [Function: lt],
    lte: [Function: lte],
    gt: [Function: gt],
    gte: [Function: gte],
    eq: [Function: eq],
    decimal: 8
  }
}
```

how do i get to amount -> amount

THIS IS THE FULL RESULT OF THE OUTPUT FROM THIS FUNCTION VIA CONSOLE.LOG

```
bal2:[object Object]
bal2 address:thor1n5u5drsxjjjcvvgrampugwzvj5zjgm6rruugf2
bal2 chain:THOR
bal2 balances[0]:[object Object]
undefined
BTC:[object Object]
ETH:[object Object]
THOR:
{
  chain: 'THOR',
  address: 'thor1n5u5drsxjjjcvvgrampugwzvj5zjgm6rruugf2',
  balances: [ { asset: [Object], amount: [Object] } ]
}
balance is:[object Object]
balances is:[object Object]
```

Comment: `const { amount: {amount: amountOfAmount} } = nameOfYourObject;`

Comment: i get this error with ur implementation.  Property 'amount' does not exist on type 'string | Balance[]'

Comment: Type `Balance` ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE. There should be no pseudocode, typos, line numbers, undeclared or unimported types or values, missing syntax, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result of the amount function like this :

```
balance.at(0).amount.amount(); // for the first balance
```

If you want the amounts of all balances :

```
const amounts = balance.map(b => b.amount.amount());
```

If you need the sum of all balances (works only if `amount()` returns a `Number`:

```
const sum = arr => arr.reduce((ps, a) => ps + a, 0);
const totalAmounts = sum(balance.map(b => b.amount.amount()));
```

Comment: i get this error, Property 'amount' does not exist on type 'string | Balance'.
  Property 'amount' does not exist on type 'string'.

Comment: i get this error when i try map, Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string | Balance[]'.
  Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.

Comment: Replace `balances` with `balance` and log `balance` please

Comment: i updated with the whole function and output

Comment: Replace `Balance` with [] should solve the issu